# What is a good beginner's antenna I can design in HFSS and create?

Tags: antenna

I'm trying to get advice from people who have used HFSS and actually designed antennas. I am starting out with HFSS, and want to create my own antenna from design to creation. I have taken an Antenna theory class, so am decently understanding of how to design different types. The hardest thing for me is thinking about what can actually be created easily, but isn't so simple as two wires separated from each other. I don't have a CNC machine, only a 3d printer. Are there any cheap antenna manufacturers for small antennas, similar to how pcb's are manufactured cheaply?

Thanks for suggestions,

Comment: Some small antennas are literally PCB traces, so in that case, the PCB manufacture methods you mention would be the cheap methods in question.

Comment: Rephrase your question because right now it sounds like a recommendation question which is off topic. Perhaps ask for DIYable antenna construction methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HFFS has a few good examples in its example circuits folder. One is a patch type of antenna and the other one a PIFA type antenna. Both can be simulated and built very easily.